# seperate java class file for jdialog box using java swing

Tags: java, swing, dialog

in this code it works right but when i press enter for the dialog box that pops out it is getting into the loop the event enter is not working right

how to write a seperate java class file for the jdialog box in order to call it from the other class  in java swing.. so that the event works correctly.
the correct output would be like like when i press enter key for the ok button the dialog box should close .please help me ..

Comment: no catch or closing bracket for try ?

Comment: so, you are pasting a part of your actual code.. :)  .. I think it would be better to comment where you skipped some things...

Comment: sir can you tell me why is the ok button on the dialog box not responding to the enter

Comment: do you mean the JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ???

Comment: yes sir i am asking you for joptionpane.showmessageDialog

Comment: can you please help mee..

Comment: please respond it is very important